What does Margo Dunne wear on her upper arm?
At around 1:50:49 you can see Margo Dunne wearing something on her upper arm that she does not have in the shots before or after which makes me think it's a movie-making equipment (a mic, perhaps). Can you identify what she is wearing?


Movie actors rarely wear body-worn microphones. For a major production like this one, the lines are typically spoken on set with a boom mike just slightly off-camera.

I believe it's her necklace, visible earlier in the scene when she's outside the house.
It's long enough to have whipped around when she sat down, and just about the right length to rest on her upper arm if she's leaning over.

